# Table with scrollable body and fixed header in rails

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am Trying to create a table with fix header and scrollable body,I tried almost every solution from stack overflow but nothing worked.
Text is getting overlapped everywhere and header is not alligned with other rows as you can see in attached image
 [table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXUn2.png)

This is my code

```css
<style>
table {
  max-width:980px;
  table-layout:fixed;
  margin:auto;
}
th, td {
  padding:5px 10px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
thead, tfoot {
  background:#f9f9f9;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  width:calc(100% - 18px);
}
tbody {
  height:300px;
  overflow:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
tbody tr {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div style="margin-left: 200px; padding-top: 50px;">
  <h1>Id  : <%= @account["id"]%></h1>
  <h1>Status : <%=@account["status"]%></h1>
  <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Document</th>
      <th>Primary Index</th>
      <th>Primary Alias</th> 
      <th>Primary Cluster</th>
      <th>Secondary Index</th>
      <th>Secondary Alias</th> 
      <th>Secondary Cluster</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @account["account_routes"].each do |route| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%=route["document"]%></td> 
        <td><%=route["primary"]["index"]%></td>
        <td><%=route["primary"]["alias"]%></td>
        <td><%=route["primary"]["cluster"]%></td> 
        <td><%=route["secondary"]["index"]%></td>
        <td><%=route["secondary"]["alias"]%></td>
        <td><%=route["secondary"]["cluster"]%></td> 
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nearly have it. Your header needs to be the same width as the columns (including the added scrollbar in the body) so that it aligns with the columns.

I added a width to the `th, td`

```
width:calc(100%/7);
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/declanmcd/xwk53p86/) here that works as expected

Comment: Actually my problem is with overflow if the size of content of a column is greater then the column width the its getting overflowed. I am seeking for some generic solution for tables with fixed headers.

Comment: Not in my example. If the text is greater than the column width it is wrapped. This is because I have set the width of the column as above. Have you tried it? Give me an example of the data.

Comment: replace document with document_document_document_document in first column of first row of tbody.

Comment: You didn't mention the specifics of the cell contents. But in that instance how do you want the contents displayed? In your example I just added the overflow to the td (see the fiddle)